# SSMS SQL Server 2008 R2 Auto Increment

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, auto-increment

Im using SQL Server Management Studio for Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.
I just need to insert a row in the middle of table with auto_increment pk.

In my tutorial example, someone could added "INDONESIA" right below "INDIA" with just simple copy-paste operation. Here is the Screenshot of the tutorial:

[image: SS_Tutorial]

I tried many times with Right Click copy + paste or Ctrl+C+V shortcut keyboard but just failed. I read a lot about inserting for auto_increment, most people stated could be done but with some workarounds.

My question, is the tutorial possibly valid? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible when you have an auto-increment field (identity) on the table.